# Active Resource return nil object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, activeresource

I try to use active resource with a server where I can see log.
I request the server with a show on a order with xml.

```
class Orders < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://"+Hello::Services.session.server+"/api/"
  self.element_name = "orders"
  self.format = ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat
end
```

> 

```
o = Hello::Services::Orders.find(o.id)
```

When I look what he returns he sends me the correct object in xml.

but when I look what I receive with this:

```
puts "====:"
puts xml
puts xml.inspect
```

the second puts return

> #< Hello::Services::Orders:0x007fc685339070>

But the third puts throw me an error:

> NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>   You might have expected an instance of Array.
>   The error occurred while evaluating nil.each):
>     app/models/user.rb:27:in `inspect'
>     app/models/user.rb:27:in`inspect'
>     app/models/user.rb:27:in `inspect'
>     app/models/user.rb:27:in`parseXml'
>     app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:47:in `order'

So if you know why I can't use my object.
For me, ActiveResource change itself received data in object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I don't know why but I succeed to print my object with .to_yaml.