# Nested route / ActiveResource valid response converted to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

I'm using ActiveResource in RoR 3.2 to get a JSON response from the Shopify API, like so:

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id],:params => {:blog_id => params[:blog_id]})

    logger.debug @article

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render @article }
    end
end
```

The ActiveResource being used takes the prefix 'blog_id', whilst 'id' is the article ID (mad given the article ID is unique, but still).

When I print @article to the console using the logger, I see:

```
#<Article:0x465b520 @attributes={"author"=>" Shopify API", "body_html"=>"Test",
 "created_at"=>"2013-06-26T06:41:12-04:00", "id"=>8204945, "published_at"=>"2013
-06-26T06:41:12-04:00", "summary_html"=>nil, "template_suffix"=>nil, "title"=>"t
est", "updated_at"=>"2013-06-26T06:41:12-04:00", "user_id"=>nil, "tags"=>""}, @
prefix_options={:blog_id=>"2812103"}, @persisted=true>
```

Hooray! However, when 'show.html.erb' attempts to render @article, I get nothing. If I render '@article.inspect', I get 'nil'

The link used to 'access' this is:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', blog_article_path(@blog.id, article.id) %>
```

I'm using the exact same technique with other objects (Blog being one), the only difference being Article is a nested resource (under 'Blog'). My routes are:

```
resources :blogs do
    resources :articles do
        resources :metafields
    end
end
```

I'm tearing my hair out trying to establish what's different between the two, to no avail. Any ideas?

**Edit**: seems similar to [Active Resource return nil object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098078/active-resource-return-nil-object/11099098#11099098), but no answer given :(

Comment: you have a typo `@article1`

Comment: Sorry, that was just a bad copy and paste. Fixed

Comment: I am not sure if this can be caused by a `respond_to` you could have in your controller, do you have this? I mean outside action.

Comment: There's a `respond_to` for each controller action (`show`, `index`, etc. etc.)

Comment: there is no respond_to in class level, right?

Comment: Just double checked, nope, not at class level

Comment: It seems this guy is having the same problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098078/active-resource-return-nil-object/11099098#11099098